# Asp.Net Core 5 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error") usage

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm going to publish a ASP.NET Core 5 project. I couldn't find any documentation about how to correctly use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")` in `Startup.cs`. I'm using `Views` folder for my `.cshtml` files. Should I put an `Error.cshtml` file globally there? If so, shouldn't a controller direct the user to error page, or Configure method can handle that?

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    SeedDatabase.Seed();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Alternatively can I use the method like `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` and put a method in `HomeController.cs` :

```
public IActionResult Error(){
    return View();
}
```

Can this cover all errors and what will be the difference from putting only "/Error" to exception handler?

Comment: Consider a search for exactly what you said you couldn't find any documentation: [app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=app.UseExceptionHandler(%22%2FError%22))

Comment: Refer : https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-exception-handling